# Powershell += is stripping out data, and .add results in many errors

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to pull a list of all Computer objects from our dozen or so AD domains in the Forest. it does that, but the problems is that the += is stripping out a number of properties. I tried using .add, but that results in errors when get-adcomputer only pulls up the name, and not IP or OS.

```
$domains = (Get-ADForest).domains

foreach ($domain in $domains) {
Get-ADComputer -Filter *  -Properties ipv4Address, OperatingSystem -Server $Domain
$complist.add($computers)
echo $computers
}
$complist |Select-Object -Property Name, ipv4Address, OperatingSystem| Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\<redacted>\Documents\computerslist.csv' -NoTypeInformation
echo $complist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its unclear what `$compList` is in your code but it is clear that is not needed to accomplish the task:

```bash
(Get-ADForest).Domains | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties ipv4Address, OperatingSystem -Server $_
} | Select-Object Name, ipv4Address, OperatingSystem |
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\<redacted>\Documents\computerslist.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

If you need output to the console for the queried computers you can add a call to `Out-Host` but this is only adding overhead to your code:

```bash
(Get-ADForest).Domains | ForEach-Object {
    $computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties ipv4Address, OperatingSystem -Server $_
    $computers | Out-Host
    $computers
} | Select-Object Name, ipv4Address, OperatingSystem |
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\<redacted>\Documents\computerslist.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```